# No Offer Letter after Verbal Offer 3 weeks back

Tags: interviewing, job-offer, behavioral-interview

I did 7 rounds of interviews for a position in one of the big IT Organizations. After the 7th round, I received a call (20th January) from HR that I have been selected and further negotiated my salary in the same call. I didn't receive an offer letter in the next couple of days.

25th Jan: Emailed HR. HR replied back that "there are some changes in organization because of which there is some delay."

Feb 1st: Called HR. Still the same answer. I asked if there is any possibility that I may not get the offer letter. HR told me that he/she does not want to commit to me. Still waiting for position approval from the hiring team and the requisition is stuck

Feb 9th: I am anxious now. I am not sure should I email or call HR.

Right now, My hope of getting an offer from the company is diminishing day by day.

Does anybody have the same experience? Did you guys finally got the offer letter or not ??

Comment: You don't have a job until you sign the offer letter. Until then, keep interviewing.

Comment: _further negotiated my salary in the same call_ I think that's the reason. I guess you were asking more than they would give you. If you want the job, call them back and demand less salary.. If you insist the salary amount, you would have to wait until someone makes the decision. They may have another candidate demanding less salary.

Answer (score 4):

> Feb 9th: I am anxious now. I am not sure should I email or call HR.

I would just look for other jobs. If they get back to you, great, but if not, at least you've resumed the job hunt.

> there are some changes in organization because of which there is some delay

Could be that the hiring manager wasn't aware that these changes were in the pipeline at the time the verbal offer was made. Maybe the company was bought out and a temporary hiring freeze was put in place for the new owner to gauge the situation. It sucks but it does happen.

Comment: The company is really big to be bought. Also, I see them hiring for senior positions for the same thing which makes me believe that budget should not be a concern

Comment: Those could be old job listings.  You asked for advice but what’s the point of the advice of you dismiss it?